# Looking for Ch.4 source code from the ebook "Digital signatures for PDF Documents"

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature, itext7

The ebook "Digital signatures for PDF Documents" available at https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/digital-signatures-pdf/intro is packed with itext example code. It is written for iText 5, and updated source code for iText 7 is at https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/addendum-digital-signatures-pdf-documents

However, I'm unable to find the iText 7 server-side source code for two examples in chapter 4 for client / server signing - c4_07_clientserversigning and c4_08_serverclientsigning. The iText 7 code i'm looking for are Code Example 4.16 and 4.18 in the original ebook.

Appreciate if anyone knows where it is available share the link. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does iText say when you ask them?

Answer (score 0):

The code examples around digital signatures can be found on [iText's GitHub repo](https://github.com/itext).

[Chapter 4 - Java](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures/tree/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter04)
and
[Chapter 4 - .NET](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/tree/develop/itext/itext.publications/itext.publications.signatures/itext/samples/signatures/chapter04)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's the servlet programs i'm looking for.

Comment: @joe1811, the servlet examples/samples did not get migrated to iText 7.